# Python Elasticsearch: using responses from search_exists

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to take a list of urls from a textfile and see if they are already in stored in elasticsearch. Here is the code:

```
import fileinput
import sys
import urllib2
import os
from urlparse import urlparse
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

for line_number, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('bangersandmash_items.csv', inplace=1)):
    if len(line) > 4:
            sys.stdout.write(line)


#open file to load URLs

with open('bangersandmash_items.csv') as urls:
    for line in urls:

        #strip out http:// as this seems to cause elasticsearch to return no results

        url = line.rstrip()
        prefix = 'http://'
        if url.startswith(prefix):
            url = url[len(prefix):]

        #query elasticsearch to see if url already exists in library's 'link' fied

        response = es.search_exists(index="websearch", doc_type="site", body={"query": {"match_phrase": {"link": url}}}, ignore=[400, 404])
            print url
            print response

            #Is url in library?

            if response == "{u'exists': true}":
                print url
                print "bingo!"
            else:
                print url
                print "nuthin."
```

It prints out the urls as formatted on lines 19-22, but it doesn't seem to handle the error code. Lines 25 and 26 print out the URL and the response from elasticsearch. Lines 28-33 don't appear to properly act on this information. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to adjust the if/else statement so that the response from elasticsearch was being read as a string out of a dictionary:

```
state = str(response['exists'])
               if state == 'True':
               print url
               print "bingo!"
               [etc].
```